# How can I create a JWT with RSA256 algorithm and a private key?

Tags: jwt

```java
String prvKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
        + "........\n"
        + "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
Jwts.builder()
        .setClaims(jwtClaim)
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, prvKey)
        .compact();
```

Running this Java code prints

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Base64-encoded key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures.  If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.

When I change RS256 to HS256 signature, token is generated well, but my target server only accepts RS256 signed token, so I have to use RS256.

The error log doesn't help me because I'm already using `signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key)` method.

How can I resolve this?

Any comments, links are appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Base64-encoded key bytes may only be specified for HMAC signatures. If using RSA or Elliptic Curve, use the signWith(SignatureAlgorithm, Key) method instead.

meant that I should pass a Key object instead of a String object.

```java
    prvKeyStr = prvKeyStr.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    prvKeyStr = prvKeyStr.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    prvKeyStr = prvKeyStr.replaceAll("\\s+","");

    byte [] prvKeyBytes = Base64.decode(prvKeyStr);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(prvKeyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey prvKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);


    return Jwts.builder()
        .setClaims(jwtClaim)
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, prvKey)
        .compact();
```

worked for me.